# Why won't my xsd file validate my xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am using C# in visual studio 2012.  I manually created the xsd file and I am creating the xml via C# from a text file.  The xsd definitions are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="BCIElectronicFormatIncoming"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="Incoming">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
```

The xml definitions are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Incoming xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/BCIElectronicFormatIncoming.xsd">
```

Here is my code that I am using for the actual validation:

```
XmlSchemaSet mySchemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
bool foundErrors = false;

mySchemaSet.Add("http://tempuri.org/BCIElectronicFormatIncoming.xsd", "BCIElectronicFormatIncoming.xsd");            

Console.WriteLine("Validating document...");            
curXDocumentRowData.Validate(mySchemaSet, (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Message);
    foundErrors = true;
});
Console.WriteLine("Current Document {0}", foundErrors ? "did not validate" : "validated");
```

When I run the validation it passes without checking the xml at all. I have gone as far as changing the name of the root element "Incoming" to random strings and it still does not catch the error. What am I doing wrong? One other issue that goes along with this is when I include the `xmlns` attribute using C# on the root element of the xml I get `xmlns=""` on every other element. I am not sure where this is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net Validate an xml against a schema (strange problem)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686086/vb-net-validate-an-xml-against-a-schema-strange-problem)

Comment: Similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110049/xsd-xml-files-pass-validation-but-so-do-xsls-and-xsds/2111136#2111136

Comment: @vendettamit Yes, and it is linked to from the first one.